# how to import chrome history into android application in android studio?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, sdk

i want the code to import chrome history into my application in android studio
and i tried to use this code :

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
String chnHistory = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history,
Cursor mycur = this.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj,
        chnHistory, null, null);
this.startManagingCursor(mycur);
mycur.moveToFirst();

ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
String title = "";
String url = "";

if (mycur.moveToFirst() && mycur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (!mycur.isAfterLast()) {
        title = mycur.getString(mycur
                .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
        url = mycur.getString(mycur
                .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        array.add(title + " : " + url);
        mycur.moveToNext();
    }
}

if (array.size() > 0) {
    for (String string : array) {
        Log.d("result ", string);
    }
}
```

but the BookmarkColumns not resolved becuase of the targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Did you find any solution? please let me know. Thanks in advance :)